# Angular2 code why its not finding lowercase value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to finding records by using `.find`. When I enter a value in small letters, it is showing `undefined`.

```
someval(value) {
    public _pagedItems : any;
    if (value.length >= 5) {
        this._pagedItems = this.allItems.find(e => e.uniqueid == value);
    }
}
```

I have data like `{ id:1, unqId: RA001 }`. When I enter `RA001` it is finding the record, but when I enter `ra001` it is `undefined`.

Comment: Is `RA001` a string? Are you just trying to make the search case insensitive?

Comment: @Hinrich  Exeactly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       someval(value){
     public _pagedItems : any;
 if(value.length>=5) { 
    this._pagedItems= this.allItems.find(e=>e.uniqueid.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase());
     }
```